# Neo4j algo.shortestPath.stream

Tags: neo4j, shortest-path

I need to execute the algo.shortestPath.stream on my graph. But I would like 
exclude some nodes in shortestPath algorithm.
Where can i insert the constraints?
This is my code:

```
MATCH (start{name:'START'}), (end{name:'END'})
CALL algo.shortestPath.stream(start, end, 'cost')
YIELD nodeId, cost
MATCH (other) WHERE id(other) = nodeId
RETURN other.name AS name, cost
```

Between START and END node there are some nodes: I would like exclude for example 'D4'.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Good question. I'm wondering about this too.